# Floating LaTeX longtabu table

Tags: tables

I have a table that takes multiple pages, so I use [longtabu](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Table_across_several_pages). However, if I embed `longtabu` in `table` environment, the table won't break into pages. How do I create a mult-page table that support floating?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. However, yours is not a problem related to `longtabu`: no float such as `table` or `figure` can be split across page. Just use `longtabu`.

Comment: You cannot, floats can only be at most one page long. You have to compromise

Comment: A very good question, I did not know this limitation of floats!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no such thing as a multipage float in LaTeX: floats are a single indivisible box. The `longtable` package provides the `longtable` environment and `tabu` generalizes it; but the `longtable` or `longtabu` environment don't float: they start where they appear in the document.